# Error: add explicit braces to avoid dangling else. C

Tags: c

I'm using gedit and my complier is clang.
I've been getting a couple of these errors recently and not sure how to fix (error in title and referring to the else statement).

```
 if(isupper(ptext[i]))
            if ((((ptext[i]+k)%26)+52) < 65 || (((ptext[i]+k)%26)+52) > 90)
            {
                printf("%c", (((ptext[i]+k)%26)+78));
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%c", (((ptext[i]+k)%26)+52));
            }
```

What should I add/remove/fix? 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Like the compiler is telling you: add some `{}` to make your intentions clearer.

Comment: note: this is not actually an error, you must be using compiler switches that turn some informational messages into errors.

Comment: To improve your code readability, use symbolic constants such as `'A'` instead of `65` and so on.

Comment: I don't see how the compiler's message is ambiguous or unclear. Did you consider following its advice?

Comment: You can hide this warning on `gcc` with `-Wno-dangling-else`.

Answer (score 12):

Your outer `if` is missing the braces:

```
if(isupper(ptext[i]))
{
        if ((((ptext[i]+k)%26)+52) < 65 || (((ptext[i]+k)%26)+52) > 90)
        {
            printf("%c", (((ptext[i]+k)%26)+78));
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c", (((ptext[i]+k)%26)+52));
        }
}
```

Personally, I would extract some of the common elements into variables:

```
char something1 = ptext[i];
if(isupper(something1))
{
    char something2 = (something1+k)%26;
    if ((something2+52) < 65 || (something2+52) > 90)
    {
        printf("%c", (something2+78));
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%c", (something2+52));
    }
}
```

And maybe even put a `char something3 = something2 + 52;` in there too. Of course, with more meaningful variable names.

Comment: @EthanT note the message is a suggestion, not actually an error.

Answer (score 5):

C is not like Python where it tells what belongs to what by indentation. Because in C, all white space is ignored.
You need to use braces to tell the compiler which `if` statement the `else` belongs to.

The C compiler doesn't know, so it's asking you to specify:

Is it this?

```
 if(isupper(ptext[i]))
 {
            if ((((ptext[i]+k)%26)+52) < 65 || (((ptext[i]+k)%26)+52) > 90)
            {
                printf("%c", (((ptext[i]+k)%26)+78));
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%c", (((ptext[i]+k)%26)+52));
            }
 }
```

or this?

```
 if(isupper(ptext[i]))
 {
            if ((((ptext[i]+k)%26)+52) < 65 || (((ptext[i]+k)%26)+52) > 90)
            {
                printf("%c", (((ptext[i]+k)%26)+78));
            }
 }
 else
 {
            printf("%c", (((ptext[i]+k)%26)+52));
 }
```

This is an example of a "dangling" else.

Comment: The C compiler _does_ know (it's the first one); it's just that the programmer may be wrong. ;)

Comment: The compiler knows because it understands the C standard — and the `else` is attached to the closest `else`-less `if` (so the code is unambiguously the first version).  However, there's a possibility that the user intended the second — that's possibly an ambiguity in the user's mind (programmer's mind).

Comment: I guess I'm the programmer getting confused with the ambiguity then. This is why I never use multiline `if` statements without braces!