# A porcupine number with c program

Tags: c

I'am new to C, please help me to solve this problem.
How to find next ***porcupine number*** with C program . According to definition A ***porcupine number***  is:

> 1. prime number
> 2. it ends in a `9`

Example: `139`

```
int findPorcupineNumber(int n)
{
   int flg;
    //first check it is prime number
    for(int i=2;i<=n/2;++i)
    {
        if(n%i==0)
        {
            flag=1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (flag==0)
        // printf("%d is a prime number.",n);

        //Now check here is last digit of number is 9
        //i did like this
        if(n%10==9){
            n/=10;
            //it is porcupine number
            //find next porcupine number
       }
        else
            printf("%d is not a prime number.",n);
    return 0;
}
```

How to find next porcupine number

Comment: What is your issue? Is it just not printing out the right number? If so, that's your algorithm.

Comment: You may find it surprising to know that `else` is not pinned to the `if` you think it is.

Comment: Try to format your code well. You'll find easily your problem..

Comment: I ca't see a declaration for `flag`.

Comment: One suggestion would be to create a prime number sieve/keep the rudimentary algorithm you have here, generate a prime number, store it, and check if the last digit is 9. If it is, print the number.

Comment: Regarding my prior comment, see this question: [Error: Add explicit braces to avoid dangling else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31599839/error-add-explicit-braces-to-avoid-dangling-else-c). I properly indented your code to amplify what that question and its answers will tell you.

Comment: The tests should probably be the other way round: You do the expensive primality check first and then check whether a number is divisible by 9. If you check divisibility by 9 up front, you'll skip many needless primality tests.

Answer (score 2):

Currently your algorithm works like this

```
1. find a prime number
2. if prime number is found 
   --> check if prime number ends with 9
             --> success
             else
             --> print "number is not prime"
```

So you if and else statements are not "connected" properly.

What you want is

```
1. find a prime number
2. if prime number is found 
   --> check if prime number ends with 9
             --> success
             else
             --> failure
   else
   --> print "number is not prime"
```

The compiler always connects the last else statement to the last if statement he finds except you tell him to do it differently by using curly brackets. Your code should look more like so:

```
if (flag == 0)
{
    if (n % 10 == 9)
    {
       print("%d is a porcupine number\n", n);
    }
}
else 
{
    printf("%d is not a prime number\n", n);
}
```

I highly recommend you to write curly brackets around every if and else statement even if the statement is followed by only one line. This will make the your more readable and less error prone.

---

Edit:

If you need to find the next porcupine number after you found the first simply return 1 if you found a porcupine number and then search until you found the next one.

```
int start = 139;
if (findPorcupineNumber(start))
{
    int n = start;
    do
    {
      n++;
    } while (!findPorcupineNumber(n)); 
    printf("next porcupine after %d is %d\n", start, n);       
}
```

Comment: it checks only porcupine number but i need to find next porcupine number

Comment: @Sailendra: Your code only checks whether `n` is a porcupine number (and it prints the result instead of returning a truth value, 0 or 1). If you want to find the next procupine number after `n`, you must probe all possible porcupine numbers after `n`. You can skip many numbers, because canduidates must follow the rule `10*k + 9`. If such a number is prime, it is also a porcupine number. Once you have a hit, return it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to keep in memory all previous prime numbers, you need to do something as this to check a number is a porcupine or is not:

```
int is_porcupine(int n)
{
    int result = 1;

    if (n % 10 == 9 && n > 1)
    {
        if (n % 3 == 0)
        {
            result = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 7; i * i <= n && result; i += 2)
            {
                result = n % i != 0;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        result = 0;
    }

    return result;
}
```

If d is the smaller divider of n and last figure of n is 9, you know d cannot be 2 or 5 (because last figure of n is 9) and you know d * d <= n. Hence the for loop.